# how can adjust divs card position

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates, tags

i want to adjust divs so the last login list come on the right of devices list

so what tags should i use and ?
[image: the view]

and this is the code :

```
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="card card-body col text-center">
            <h5>All devices </h5>
            <hr>            
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
....
                    </tr>   
                    {% for device in devices %}
                        <tr>
                            ..... 
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}        
                </table>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-body col text-center">
            <h5>Last login </h5>
            <hr>            
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                    ....                    
                        </tr>
{% endfor %}        
                </table>    
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi did you check the below given answers.. if it helped you upvote those answers and mark one of them as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try

```
   <div class="row">
        <div class="card card-body col-md-6 text-center">
            <h5>All devices </h5>
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="card card-body col-md-6 text-center">
            <h5>Last login </h5>
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
```

See [Bootstrap Grid System](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

Answer (score 0):

If it's a regular bootstrap, you just can add "col-12 col-md-6"

```
<div class="card card-body col-12 col-md-6 text-center">
```

to your div with "card" class.